# xcode how to modify compiled source code running a pre build script

Tags: xcode, compilation

I'm trying to add some functionality to several of my xcode projects.
I'd like to have an external program called pre build and modify some of the code being later compiled, without actually changing my source code (I wouldn't like to actually see the modifications taking place).

Is this possible? If so, can anyone please direct me to the right way of accomplishing this?